# How to check user authentication from many db tables by turns?

Tags: php, authentication, yii2

I am using yii2 advanced template and have many user tables. For example `Table_1`, `Table_2`, `Table_3`. How can I make user authentication on different tables by turns? Like `check Table_1: if !authenticated: check Table_2: if !authenticated: check Table_3: if !authenticated: denied`?

I don't know how extend multiple `User` classes:

```
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%user}}';
    }

    ...
```

LoginForm class:

```
<?php
namespace common\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

/**
 * Login form
 */
class LoginForm extends Model
{
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe = true;

    private $_user = false;


    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // username and password are both required
            [['username', 'password'], 'required'],
            // rememberMe must be a boolean value
            ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
            // password is validated by validatePassword()
            ['password', 'validatePassword'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Validates the password.
     * This method serves as the inline validation for password.
     *
     * @param string $attribute the attribute currently being validated
     * @param array $params the additional name-value pairs given in the rule
     */
    public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
    {
        if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
            $user = $this->getUser();
            if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect username or password.');
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logs in a user using the provided username and password.
     *
     * @return boolean whether the user is logged in successfully
     */
    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by [[username]]
     *
     * @return User|null
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        if ($this->_user === false) {
            $this->_user = User::findByUsername($this->username);
        }

        return $this->_user;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function actionLogin()
    {
        if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            return $this->goBack();
        } else {
            return $this->render('login', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do.

In **LoginForm.php** edit `getUser()` function as this

```
public function getUser()
{
    if ($this->_user === false) {
        $this->_user = User::findByUsername($this->username);
    }

    //to check if user not found in first table then check in another
    if(!$this->_user){
        $this->_user = UserTwo::findByUsername($this->username);
    }


    //you can add more for more tables


    return $this->_user;
}
```

generate **UserTwo.php** model using **Gii** and change to following:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class UserTwo extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'user_two';
    }

    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return static::findOne(['id' => $id]);
    }

    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException('"findIdentityByAccessToken" is not implemented.');
    }

    public static function findByUsername($username)
    {
        return static::findOne(['username' => $username]);
    }

    public static function findByPasswordResetToken($token)
    {
        if (!static::isPasswordResetTokenValid($token)) {
            return null;
        }

        return static::findOne([
            'password_reset_token' => $token
        ]);
    }

    public static function isPasswordResetTokenValid($token)
    {
        if (empty($token)) {
            return false;
        }
        $expire = Yii::$app->params['user.passwordResetTokenExpire'];
        $parts = explode('_', $token);
        $timestamp = (int)end($parts);
        return $timestamp + $expire >= time();
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->getPrimaryKey();
    }

    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->auth_key;
    }

    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        return $this->getAuthKey() === $authKey;
    }

    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password_hash);
    }
}
```